# ip address of mysql server

Tags: mysql, android

I am working with ubuntu 16.04 and developing and android app, I want to fetch data from mysql server to my android application through jdbc. In order to do that I want URL for connection. And for correct url I need an IP address. Now I do not understand which IP address should I put into that URL. When I used the command,`hostname -i` it gives me the result 127.0.1.1 and when I used the command, `ifconfig` I get the 127.0.0.1 which one should I use. Or Inshort how to get the ip address of mysql server for jdbc connection.

Comment: MySQL traditionally used port 3306. 127.0.0.1:3306 should work.

Comment: ok thanks, I will assume that 127.0.0.1 is correct

Comment: `localhost:3306` is an alternative.